# Mojolicious running on Raspberry Pi sends empty sessions to Safari on iPhone

Tags: iphone, perl, safari, raspberry-pi2, mojolicious

I'm writing a Perl server for my church using Mojolicious::Lite that will run on a Raspberry Pi 2.  I wrote the software on my laptop running Linux Mint and have tested it along the way on the Raspberry Pi.  My most recent addition was a simple login screen that stores an authentication in a session. It works fine when running on the laptop, and can be accessed from Firefox and Chrome on Linux and Chrome and Safari from my iPhone. When the same code runs on the Raspberry, it works for everything but Safari on the iPhone. The Safari shows a 0 byte cookie in the Settings->Safari->Advanced->Website Data.  The same version of Mojolicious is running on both the laptop and the Raspberry (6.14). I get the same results with the simple example in the Mojolicious::Guides::Tutorial that increments a counter. When using the Safari iPhone browser to look at the counter on the laptop, the counter increments and the stored cookie is .2kb, but when looking at the same code running on the Raspberry, the counter never increments and the cookie is 0 bytes. Here is the sample code:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Access session data in action and template
get '/counter' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->session->{counter}++;
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ counter.html.ep
Counter: <%= session 'counter' %>
```

On my laptop I am running Linux Mint with Perl 5.18.2 and Mojolicious 6.14.  On the Raspberry, I am running Raspbian Wheezy, with Perl 5.14.2 (the latest available with the default archives when doing apt-get) and Mojolicious 6.14. Any help you could offer in getting this working would be greatly appreciated.
  Thanks!
  Garry

Comment: you can try MOJO_DAEMON_DEBUG=1 morbo script/yourappname to see if it is printing correct Set-Cookie etc. to Safari. can't comment more since I do not have Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found the problem and resolved it.  It wasn't the different versions of Mojolicious, the different versions of Perl, different modules or different libraries.  The problem was that, when I set up the Raspberry last month, I didn't take the time to set up ntpd.  So when the power went out last week, the time didn't reset properly when the Raspberry started back up.  After trying many, many things, I happened to notice this morning that the time reported was off by about 2 1/2 hours.  Resetting the clock brought the world back to normal.  Apparently, the Safari browser was looking at the incoming cookie, seeing that its expiration date (now + 1 hr) was in the past, and since it was expired, not storing it.  Anyway, that's what it took to resolve the problem, and I feel pretty foolish for not catching it sooner.  Thanks for your help.